# Get-ChildItem is failing in case one of folders in share path is not accessible

Tags: powershell

I am using `Get-ChildItem` to iterate through a share path which have many folders and I am checking for a specific file in those folders and according to some checks related to date and time.

Problem: If any of the folder in the share path is not accessible then the `Get-ChildItem` is failing and not progressing ahead.

Is there a way to silently continue to the next folder in case one of the folder is not accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the `-ErrorAction` switch

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```